# Why should you runtime cast in C++?

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain the difference between the following three lines of code:

```
char *Text = static_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hData));
char *Text = (char*)GlobalLock(hData);
char *Text = dynamic_cast<char*>(GlobalLock(hData));
```

I understand that the compiler will build some kind of reference tables for C++ runtime casting, but why? What is the advantage here?

Comment: While I'm not sure what the (dis)advantages of each technique on locks may be, I do know that static casting for primitives is generally optimal and dynamic casts for object-oriented programs are generally preferable as they reduce the memory overheads of your program.

Comment: The first line is correct C++ code, the second line is C code, the third line is not understanding how dynamic_cast can detect invalid casts on C++ objects and throw an exception, GlobalLock does not return a C++ object.

Comment: @patrickjp93: Neither are `dynamic_cast`s preferable over `static_cast`s, nor do they have any effect on a program's memory footprint. They are simply different things. You probably should go back to your introductory C++ material, if your choice for using a `dynamic_cast` is based on the 'object-orientedness' of a program.